# Azure SQL Server takes 10 times as long as a on-premise SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, azure-sql-database, sqlclient

I have a Visual Studio VB.NET project that basically runs a large number of queries against a database.

After moving the database from a local on-premise SQL Server to Azure SQL, the performance dropped significantly.

Of course it will be slower. But it's 10 times slower...
Latency is of-course the issue here.

Are there any ways to increase speed? Something "smart" in the connection string or command object?

I cannot change the "architecture" of the project (out of my hands). It has to be a lot (5000+) of small queries that return one value (running one at the time).

Here is an example of what I mean. Running this on a "local" SQL Server takes 10 seconds - in Azure, it takes 200 seconds:

```
Dim Server As String = "AZURE.poweranalyzedevazuretest.database.windows.net"
Dim User As String = "*****"
Dim password As String = "******!"
Dim PRODUCTIONDATABASE As String = "MYDB"

Dim SQL_CONNECTION_STRING As String = "Server=" & Server & "; Database=" & PRODUCTIONDATABASE & "; User Id=" & User & "; Password=" & password & ";"

Dim SDataSet = New DataSet
Dim SDataAdapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
Dim SCommand As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
Dim CurrConnection = New SqlConnection(SQL_CONNECTION_STRING)
CurrConnection.Open()
Debug.Print(Now().ToString)

For i = 1 To 1000
    SCommand.Connection = CurrConnection
    SCommand.CommandText = "SELECT 'Hello World'"
    Dim p As Object = SCommand.ExecuteScalar()
Next

CurrConnection.Close()
Debug.Print(Now().ToString)
```

/perove

Comment: Are you running the client application on-prem in both cases?

Comment: Azure sql is by no means a copy of sql server on premise. its a different database that has different constraints. For instance your on premise db might be optimized to minimize cpu usage at expense of page reads but on azure this optimization can be detrimental to performance. You would need to profile your queries and optimize them or at least reconsider indexes to improve performance. Good clustering index that actually groups data the way it is read can be the biggest performance boost.

Comment: Latency is a thing. Assuming it only takes 10ms to `select 'Hello World'` on-prem (and it's probably less) then you only need 100ms of latency between you and Azure for it to be 10x slower.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning true it can be, but I'm working with Azure sql on my laptop every day sending queries from PL using mobile phone network connection over vpn in HU to data center somewhere in west EU and latency its not a big deal. OP is not selecting Hello world as he claims it takes 10s on on premise which would be ridiculous performance, that query is just placeholder for the real one.

Comment: FWIW, I ran your code against an on-prem instance and it ran in well under 1 second. Same code against Azure SQL Database (basic tier) ran in 60 seconds. This is measuring network latency, not database performance. I would expect much less latency running the code in Azure, especially in the same region as the db.

Comment: Generally you wouldn't execute 1000 separate queries in rapid succession. You would one big query which returns 1000 rows. So this test is bogus, as the increase in latency would be much smaller. Side note: you should have `Using` on the connection and command objects

Comment: Tnx for all the input.  @DanGuzman: Yes. on-prem on both.  (This is also the typcal scenario this program will run under.)  Latency is of-course the issue here. I Just tought the diffrence where so big. 10-20 (sometimes 30) times  slower.

Comment: @DanGuzman :Yes running the samplecode on a Azure VS located in the same region as Azure SQL reduces the time dramaticly. Speed almost as the local solution.

Comment: You didn't mention the tier - keep in mind that the lowest tier is basically a rusty laptop that they found in a dumpster.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code against an on-prem SQL Server instance and it ran in well under 1 second. Same code against Azure SQL Database (basic tier) ran in 60 seconds. This test is measuring network latency rather than database performance.

I expect running the code in Azure, especially in the same region as the db, will provide performance comparable to running both on-prem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you run the application on premises and connect to an Azure SQL Database, by default, it uses the proxy method of connection and has to negotiate connection each time. Whereas if you connect from an Azure Virtual Machine it will be much faster because, by default, it only has to negotiate connection once (redirect method), and does not have to do it again. I think you can change this default, but it may involve opening ports or something. Perhaps better to run in a Virtual Machine if possible.

This is explained near the end of this Microsoft YouTube video (1hr 53mins)
[Learn Live - Intro to Azure SQL Deployment and Configuration | Azure SQL Bootcamp (Session 1)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wntLOJRvIeI&list=PLlrxD0HtieHjveswk8_gkPD42Te48X4zG&index=1&t=1146s)

It was your statement "It has to be a lot (5000+) of small queries that return one value (running one at the time)." that made me realise that this is probably your answer.

[Connectivity Architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-architecture?view=azuresql)

[SQL Connectivity Architecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdMfl4OlgPQ&list=PLlrxD0HtieHi5c9-i_Dnxw9vxBY-TqaeN&index=16)

See [Networking, Connectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-settings?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal) for the Azure SQL Server.